# Delegate Function Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uicollectionviewdelegate

So I am trying to use protocols and delegates to connect two functions so I can perform some operation on a variable a collectionView in this case in a different file.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
protocol EventCollectionCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func setupCollectionView(for eventCollectionView: UICollectionView?)
}
class EventCollectionCell:UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var delegate: EventCollectionCellDelegate?

    var eventArray = [EventDetails](){
        didSet{
            self.eventCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var enentDetails:Friend?{
        didSet{

            var name = "N/A"
            var total = 0
            seperator.isHidden = true
            if let value = enentDetails?.friendName{
                name = value
            }
            if let value = enentDetails?.events{
                total = value.count
                self.eventArray = value
                seperator.isHidden = false
            }
            if let value = enentDetails?.imageUrl{
                profileImageView.loadImage(urlString: value)
            }else{
                profileImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tokyo")
            }

            self.eventCollectionView.reloadData()
            setLabel(name: name, totalEvents: total)
        }
    }

    let container:UIView={
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
        return view
    }()
    //profile image view for the user
    var profileImageView:CustomImageView={
        let iv = CustomImageView()
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        iv.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        iv.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return iv
    }()
    //will show the name of the user as well as the total number of events he is attending
    let labelNameAndTotalEvents:UILabel={
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()

    let seperator:UIView={
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    //collectionview that contains all of the events a specific user will be attensing
    let flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    lazy var eventCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flow)

//    var eventCollectionView:UICollectionView?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setUpCell()
        self.setupCollectionView(for: eventCollectionView)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func setupCollectionView(for eventCollectionView: UICollectionView?){
        delegate?.setupCollectionView(for: eventCollectionView)
    }
    }
```

This is the file that creates a collectionViewCell with a collectionView in it. I am trying to perform some operation on that collectionView using the delegate pattern. My problem is that the delegate function is never called in the accompanying viewController. I feel like I have done everything right but nothing happens in the accompanying vc. Anyone notice what could possibly be wrong.
I have shown the code for the VC below

```
class FriendsEventsView: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,EventCollectionCellDelegate {
    var friends = [Friend]()
    var followingUsers = [String]()
    var height:CGFloat = 0
    var notExpandedHeight : CGFloat = 50
    var isExpanded = [Bool]()
    //so this is the main collectonview that encompasses the entire view
    lazy var mainCollectionView:UICollectionView={
        // the flow layout which is needed when you create any collection view
        let flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        //setting the scroll direction
        flow.scrollDirection = .vertical
        //setting space between elements
        let spacingbw:CGFloat = 5
        flow.minimumLineSpacing = spacingbw
        flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        //actually creating collectionview
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flow)
        //register a cell for that collectionview
        cv.register(EventCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "events")
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //changing background color
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        //sets the delegate of the collectionView to self. By doing this all messages in regards to the  collectionView will be sent to the collectionView or you.
        //"Delegates send messages"
        cv.delegate = self
        //sets the datsource of the collectionView to you so you can control where the data gets pulled from
        cv.dataSource = self
        //sets positon of collectionview in regards to the regular view
        cv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(spacingbw, 0, spacingbw, 0)
        return cv

    }()

    lazy var eventCollectionView:UICollectionView={
        let flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flow.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let spacingbw:CGFloat = 5
        flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flow)
        //will register the eventdetailcell
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.register(EventDetailsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "eventDetails")
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(spacingbw, 0, spacingbw, 0)
        cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        cv.bounces = false
        return cv
    }()

    func setupCollectionView(for eventCollectionView: UICollectionView?) {
        print("Attempting to create collectonView")
        eventCollectionView?.backgroundColor = .blue
    }

    //label that will be displayed if there are no events
    let labelNotEvents:UILabel={
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .lightGray
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.text = "No events found"
        label.isHidden = true
        return label
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //will set up all the views in the screen
        self.setUpViews()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "close_black").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.goBack))
    }

    func setUpViews(){
        //well set the navbar title to Friends Events
        self.title = "Friends Events"
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        //adds the main collection view to the view and adds proper constraints for positioning
        view.addSubview(mainCollectionView)
        mainCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mainCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mainCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mainCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        //adds the label to alert someone that there are no events to the collectionview and adds proper constrains for positioning
        mainCollectionView.addSubview(labelNotEvents)
        labelNotEvents.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainCollectionView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        labelNotEvents.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainCollectionView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        //will fetch events from server
        self.fetchEventsFromServer()

    }
    // MARK: CollectionView Datasource for maincollection view
//woll let us know how many cells are being displayed
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(friends.count)
        isExpanded = Array(repeating: false, count: friends.count)
        return friends.count
    }
    //will control the size of the cell that is displayed in the containerview
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        height = 100
        let event = friends[indexPath.item]
        if let count = event.events?.count,count != 0{
            height += (CGFloat(count*40)+10)
        }
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: height)
    }
    //will do the job of effieicently creating cells for the eventcollectioncell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "events", for: indexPath) as! EventCollectionCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.enentDetails = friends[indexPath.item]
        cell.eventCollectionView = eventCollectionView
        return cell
    }
```

}

I have cut the code down to what I believe is needed to answer the question for simplicity. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The `setupCollectionView` function is being called in the `init` but that will occur before the delegate has been set.

Comment: okay so are there any changes you would suggest to get the functionality I want

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth the way I need it to with the cell setting the delegate

Comment: What is going to trigger a call to the delegate? I can't see one in the code you have posted.

Comment: @Nick the calling of the function setupCollectionView should trigger the call

Comment: I would suggest abandoning the delegate idea for this action (you can keep it for other actions).  If you are always going to be setting up the cell in it's initialiser then the collection view should be safe to assume that has happened although as the eventCollectionView is optional nothing will happen if it's not setup.  Even better would be to only handle the setup inside the cell itself as that should really be responsible for it's own views not delegating the responsibility up to the view controller.

Comment: ok thats what I had the first time but I figured it was bad practice to have all of that in the cell controller

Answer (score 0):

You set `delegate` after `setupCollectionView`. In your case, you can't call `setupCollectionView` before you set `delegate`, because `setupCollectionView` called in `init`

Comment: the way I need it to with the cell setting the delegate

Comment: If you can not do without a delegate, than remove `setupCollectionView` from `init` and call it after you set delegate (in `collectionView(:, cellForItemAt:` method)

Comment: I recommend that you don't use delegate pattern in this case. You can just do what you want with collection view in `collectionView(:, cellForItemAt:)` method. For example: `cell.collectionView.backgroundColor = .blue`

Comment: can i still set the datasource and delegate methods for that collectionView

Comment: because when i called it in the didSet method it did call the function of course but it did nothing to the actual collectionView

Comment: Of course, you can set dataSource and delegate for that collectionView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164909/discussion-between-ron-baker-and-ilya-kharabet).

Comment: if you calling something in didSet before `init`will be called, nothing will happen